# Pyside Installation Error

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I have a 32-bit Windows 7 OS. Today, I tried downloading the PySide setup program. However, after I try running the downloaded file, I get the following error: "PySide Setup program invalid or damaged."

Why am I getting this? I have recently started a course on building GUI applications with Python using the Qt framework, and need PySide for the same. I use Python 2.7 btw.

Comment: are you sure you got the 32-bit version of the installer?

Comment: Did you dowload from [PySide Binaries for Microsoft Windows](https://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows)?

Comment: Yes. This is the hyperlink I used to download the setup: PySide-1.2.1.win32-py2.7.exe [download.qt-project.org]. Also, have tried reinstalling 3 times now. Still getting the same error.

Comment: try to install PySide via setuptools, it will download the right version of binaries depending on your python version. Install setuptools [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools] and run the following command: easy_install PySide

Comment: is there any other method? All I get after clicking on the download link of setuptools is a python code and I can't figure out what to do next. No other method for installing PySide?

Comment: have you even try to read the documentation on how to install setuptools ? this is copy-pasted from setuptools PyPI page (what part is not clear to you ?): INSTALLING PYSIDE ON WINDOWS: The recommended way to install setuptools on Windows is to download ez_setup.py[https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py] and run it. The script will download the appropriate .egg file and install it for you.

Comment: Has *anyone* gotten a fix for this?  I am currently having the same exact problem with matplotlib's basemap toolkit, using the correct Windows installer on Windows 7 64-bit.  I've found the same thing on the net under various Python installers, so it's not an isolated problem...

Answer (score 0):

My solution to nearly the same exact problem was simply that it needed to be installed with admin privileges, so that might be your issue also.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using Pip.
download that https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run it with your python.

then open a cmd window at your pip instal directory in my case: C:\Python27\Scripts

then type in:  `pip install -U PySide`