# Python package installation error - chronic issue

Tags: python, windows, installation

My situation is as follows, but it's clear to me that it is a wider-reaching symptom than just one package.  I am trying to install basemap, the matplotlib toolkit, on Windows 7 64-bit.  I have an installation of Anaconda 1.9.  I downloaded the relevant Windows executable from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/), but cannot get it installed.  When I execute the installer it says:

> The file exists.  Could not create temporary file

When I click 'OK' it says:

> The setup program is invalid or damaged.

I have tried the executables for different versions of basemap and get the same thing.

This is *exactly* the same behavior as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588259/pyside-installation-error) question ... apologies for the "duplicate", but this illustrates that it has nothing to do with the particular package (PySide for that one, basemap for me).  I've found people asking questions about the same behavior for various Python installers across the net, but nobody has written a solution (that I can find).  And always **Python** installers.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running the installer with administrator privileges? I know that Basemap has several C extensions it compiles, and so it's possible that on your particular system it needs admin privileges to do so.

Comment: @aruisdante no, I unfortunately don't have access to an admin just at this moment, or I would have ... they all have their hair on fire over something else.  Do you think that is the issue?  I wonder why these particular error messages occur if it is....

Comment: Because it's trying to write a temporary compilation file to a directory that I doesn't have access to. Permission errors often result in 'file not found' type errors. I'm not saying that's definitely what it is, but it's worth a shot if you can do it.

Comment: Aha! Sensible.  I can try to recreate this at home, and see if admin priv is the key.

Comment: @aruisdante indeed, you are correct - everything works fine if installing with admin privileges.  Such a simple answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the illuminating comments disappear, the answer to this question was merely that **administrative privileges are required for the install**.  Leaving this question up so it may be found, because when searching I found many similar questions that had no answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, the admin privileges did not solve the issue for me, when I emptied the windows temp folder, then it worked.